# String replace in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<?php
$str = "this is a . test . string.";
?>

<script>
    var str = '<?php echo $str; ?>';
    wordss = ' . ';
    var res = str.replace(new RegExp(wordss,"g"),". "); //space(.)space convert to (.)space
    console.log(res);
</script>
```

***Output***

```
this is. . test. string.
```

I want it in  "**this is a. test. string.**"

Comment: `var res = str.replace(/ \. /g, ". ");` - you have to quote the `.` character, and it's easier to use regex literals.

Comment: Also, you will want to do: `var str = <?php echo json_encode($str); ?>;` to avoid special characters from spilling over into your JavaScript.

Comment: how can i use a variable because i want to check multiple values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "this is a . test . string.";
var res = str.split(" . ").join(". ");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegExp` `/\s+(?=\.)/g` to match space character that is followed by `.` character

```js
var str = "this is a . test . string."
str = str.replace(/\s+(?=\.)/g, "");
document.body.textContent = str;
```